# need help identifying this exception on android app

Tags: android

working with my android app, i get this exception when opening an activity from another activity. i need your help identifying where on my code should I begin to solve the issue:

```
04-16 19:55:43.014: I/MemoryCache(1083): MemoryCache will use up to 4.0MB
04-16 19:55:43.044: D/AndroidRuntime(1083): Shutting down VM
04-16 19:55:43.054: W/dalvikvm(1083): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a53ba8)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083): Process: com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria, PID: 1083
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria/com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.Empresas_SingleItemView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getCacheDir(ContextWrapper.java:230)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.FileCache.<init>(FileCache.java:17)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.ImageLoader.<init>(ImageLoader.java:34)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.Empresas_SingleItemView.<init>(Empresas_SingleItemView.java:16)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
04-16 19:55:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     ... 11 more
```

EDITED: Added Empresa.SingleItemView.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Empresas_SingleItemView extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    String valoracionEmpresa;
    String nombreEmpresa;
    String direccionEmpresa;
    String imagenstrImagen;
    String position;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.empresas_singleitemview);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Get the result of rank
        valoracionEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("valoracionEmpresa");
        // Get the result of country
        nombreEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("nombreEmpresa");
        // Get the result of population
        direccionEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("direccionEmpresa");
        // Get the result of flag
        imagenstrImagen = i.getStringExtra("strImagen");

        // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
        TextView txtvaloracionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoracionEmpresa);
        TextView txtnombreempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombreEmpresa);
        TextView txtdireccionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.direccionEmpresa);

        // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
        ImageView imagenEmpresa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.strImagen);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtvaloracionempresa.setText(valoracionEmpresa);
        txtnombreempresa.setText(nombreEmpresa);
        txtdireccionempresa.setText(direccionEmpresa);

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imagenstrImagen, imagenEmpresa);
    }
}
```

Added FileCache.java

```
import java.io.File;
import android.content.Context;

public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context) {
        // Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir = new File(
                    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "JsonParseTutorialCache");
        else
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url) {
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        // String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear() {
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        if (files == null)
            return;
        for (File f : files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

Added ImageLoader.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    // Handler to display images in UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.temp_img;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // Download Images from the Internet
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            // Recommended Size 512
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Impossible to tell unless you post your code.

Comment: @Squonk, I don't have any problem to post my code, but what file do you need to see? I guess it is too much to put all files code. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: From the logcat I can only guess it would be `com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.Empresas_SingleItemView`

Comment: @Squonk, nice, I am posting it right now, I will tell you when done. Thank you.

Comment: @Squonk, you can see it posted below the exception text.

Comment: Is the line 16 `new ImageLoader(this);`?

Comment: @Fllo line 16 is: ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

Comment: Right, I suspect that `this` doesn't return the context because it is not attached yet with your current activity.

Comment: @mvasco : Yes, the comment from Fllo suggested that. Move that line into `onCreate(...)`

Comment: @Squonk, I have done what you say, but the same exception is thrown

Comment: I'm just guessing but in your file `FileCache` you're making a call to `getCacheDir` I believe. This can return null which can lead to your null pointer exception.

Comment: @singularhum, I have posted FileCache.java to my question, may be it is easier to you to see if there may be an error.

Comment: yep I think your issue is this line `if (!cacheDir.exists())` which is line 17 as specified in the log. `cacheDir` is null. So it looks like the external storage is not mounted and the internal cache directory is returning null?

Comment: @singularhum, then I should try to mount the external storage. Do you know if I need a real device to test it or could I simulate an external storage at the simulator?

Comment: Just to confirm which line is 17 in FileCache?

Comment: @singularhum, line 17 in FileCache is :  cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();

Comment: oh so the others may be right, is `context` null?

Comment: @singularhum, how can I know if context is null?

Comment: A condition with a log might help. if(context == null) Log.v(...);

Comment: @singularhum,just before line 17 i guess?

Comment: That was Fllo but sure. Can you also post ImageLoader. I suspect the error occurs in the actual getCacheDir call so context would not be null.

Comment: @singularhum, of course, i will post it right now...

Comment: @singularhum, ImageLoader posted, but it is working for other activities inside the app.

Comment: but is context null using what Fllo supplied? Or by debugging?

Comment: @singularhum, sorry for the delay, I don't see the log output from line 17.

Comment: are you sure `ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);` is in the `onCreate` of `Empresas_SingleItemView` as Fllo mentioned? I was able to reproduce your error when using `this` in the declarations instead of `onCreate`

Comment: I think, you're definitely right @singularhum, the Logcat says: `NPE at getCacheDir(ContextWrapper...)` when mvasco uses `context.getCacheDir();`.

Comment: @singularhum, I am having problems with my simulator, i will try to execute the app again. Now I am sure the sentence is in the onCreate and not in the declarations... l

Comment: @Fllo yeah that's what I thought too, but since it's a `ContextWrapper`, so when `new ImageLoader(this)` in declarations is called the base context isn't set in ContextWrapper I believe which is why the the log shows it in there.

Comment: @singularhum, the log is not shown but the exception persists with the line inside onCreate

Comment: Just in case, are you sure that you don't forget the `{ }` for the *else condition* with your log? We all forgot once ;)

Comment: @Fllo, may be, let me check it, but to be sure, would you mind writing down the whole log sentence for me as it should be?

Comment: @Fllo, I am running the app again with the new logging condition.

Comment: @Fllo, it is not shown either.

Comment: That's incredible! Well.. I don't know why. It should. And (keep the log) when you use another activity which uses this class too, is it showing?

Comment: Try uninstalling and re-installing, it looks like your "new" code isn't being used. The code SHOULD work when included in `onCreate`. Refer to the `getCacheDir` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.getCacheDir%28%29). If `mBase` is null that is your npe which occurs when in declarations (I tested this myself). Oh and you can access mBase using `((ContextWrapper)context).getBaseContext();`

Comment: @singularhum,I will do it now, thanks

Comment: @Fllo, ImageLoader is used by other activities, and no exception is shown. ImageLoader do make calls to FileCache, and no error. Only when trying to open Empresas_SingleItemView activity is the exception thrown.

Comment: @singularhum, I have uninstalled and reinstalled the app, the exceptions is thrown, and the log is not shown either.

Comment: Did you rebuild your project before installing it back? Try adding a log statement not inside an if statement so that it should log every time. If it's not logging then your code is still not being including.

Comment: @singularhum, I am on it,thank you

Comment: @singularhum, context != null, sure, it is logging it only with the condition context!=null.

Comment: Okay looks like your code is included. Do you still get the exception with the code in `onCreate`?

Comment: @singularhum, yes sure, the line: ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this); is inside onCreate

Comment: @singularhum, I do appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: @Fllo, context != null, for sure, it appears on the log cat.

Comment: no problem, I was pretty sure, as the others suggested, that the putting it there would work.. dunno why it doesn't work. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: @singularhum, I don't want you to spend more time because of my issue, but if I could send you my project may be you could find the problem easier than myself, I am not very expert with Android.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50830/discussion-between-singularhum-and-mvasco)

Comment: @singularhum, I have it. The problem lies on the lines: // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
        TextView txtvaloracionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoracionEmpresa);
        TextView txtnombreempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombreEmpresa);
        TextView txtdireccionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.direccionEmpresa);

        // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
        ImageView imagenEmpresa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.strImagen);

Comment: @Fllo , I have it. The problem lies on the lines: // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
        TextView txtvaloracionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoracionEmpresa);
        TextView txtnombreempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombreEmpresa);
        TextView txtdireccionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.direccionEmpresa);

        // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
        ImageView imagenEmpresa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.strImagen);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long discussions and searching time, I have found where the problem lies. I don't know how to solve it yet, but at least, I know how to avoid the exception.
May be tomorrow, with fresher mind, I will solve the source problem, but for now it is enough getting the app execute without exceptions.
Here:

```
   // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
    TextView txtvaloracionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoracionEmpresa);
    TextView txtnombreempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombreEmpresa);
    TextView txtdireccionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.direccionEmpresa);

    // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
    ImageView imagenEmpresa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.strImagen);
```

Commenting these lines (putting // on all of them), the exception is not shown and the activity Empresas_SingleItemView appears. Of course, the values are not the real values,  but now the way to the solution appears to be very easy. Thank you for all your support.

Comment: Hi Mvasco, did you check if these views have the right ids in *empresas_singleitemview.xml*?